# How will I resize a linked list if a function already has a pointer to the node that needs to be deleted?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Lets say, I have singly linkedlist with 5 elements in it. How will I resize the list if I delete an element with this specific situation -

My singly linkedlist is defined as `0->1->2->3->4`, where these numbers are the index of the list. Suppose I have function, `f()` which return a pointer directly at index 2. From here, I want to delete 2 but don't know how to connect 1 to 3. How can I do that?

Comment: You have to maintain data structures with a reference to "next"...have a value that can be compared to identify that member.  Whether it be the address itself or a unique hash or ....you get it.

Comment: It sounds like you have an array, not a linked list. Seeing your code would make this easier to understand.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I believe OP might have some semantics they're mixing up.  The "index" is just the order they are referenced in.

Comment: Yeah I was using "index" as a reference to the order only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the case of a "singley-linked" list you will need to maintain the data-structure of for the "next" item in the list.

If in your case (it seems as though you are) constricted to use a function that returns a pointer to this link, then you can loop through and delete accordingly.

For example:

```
struct link *f(struct link *head) {
    // Do work...
    // is found struct link *target
    return target;
}

struct link *delete_link(struct link *head, struct link *target) {
    if (head == target) {
        struct link *tmp = head;
        struct link *new_head = tmp->next;
        return new_head;
    }

    struct link *curr = head;
    while (curr->next != target) {
        struct link *tmp = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = target->next
    free(target);
    return head;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct link {
        // data
        struct link *next;
    };

    // Construct list....
    struct link *head = construct_list(1, 2, 3, 4);
    // Do stuff...
    struct link *target = f(list);
    // Found a deletion target...
    head = delete_link(target);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "then you can loop through and delete accordingly." - this is what I am trying to avoid. My constriction is that I cannot access `1` from the linkedlist if I am deleting `2`.

Comment: @Jezues Yes. That is a consequence of your data model.